# Is $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ a normal subgroup in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $N=\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $M=\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$. Is $M$ normal subgroup in $N$? Why or why not?

I know how to do this with $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ but with $N=\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $M=\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ I don't even know all of their elements so I can't check the left and right cosets of $M$ in $N$.

Comment: $det (ABA^{-1})= det B$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that $H$ is normal in $G$ if $ghg^{-1} \in H$ for all $g \in G$, $h \in H$. Also note that for square matrices $A, B$ we have $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Is the determinant map

$$\det:GL_n(\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R^*\,$$

a homomorphism....?

Comment: I haven't learn about homomorphism yet

Comment: Then I can't understand how you're dealing with this kind of questions...but perhaps it's only me and my way of seeing the order of teachind and learning stuff.

Comment: @DonAntonio Since for any element in the special group, $\det A=\det A^{-1}=1$, $\det AB=\det A\det B$ means conjugations by elements of the special group preserve determinants. It would have been more useful to write that instead of resorting to homomorphisms, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm with @DonAntonio on this one. Maybe a "homomorphism" is a more abstract concept than a normal subgroup, but it's difficult understanding why you would care about normal subgroups without knowing about homomorphisms.

Comment: (at the OP - this isn't meant as anything negative about you, of course! Just a comment that it's frustrating when things are presented in this order.)

Comment: In defence of the OP, I usually teach things in the order: normal subgroups and quotient groups, homomorphisms and their kernels and images, isomorphism theorems. They all come together, but this would still be a reasonable exercise to set immediately after defining normal subgroups and before going onto homomorphisms.

Comment: This is *group theory* stuff, and they obviously are not only studying normal subgroups but even seeing some not-so-elementary examples, as matrix groups. I'm used that at this stage (and even pretty earlier), homomorphism have already been covered. That's all. It's ridiculous now to argue that "the determinant product theorem can be known without the abstract notion (?!?) of homomorphism" , etc., as if "homomorphism" is more abstract than determinant, matrix or the special linear group...specially after, apparently, having done at least basic linear algebra, full with homomorphisms!

Comment: This is just one example more of the need to know more about the askers. It'd be nice to have a thingy that when somebody asks a question here **forces** the asker to give some info about her/his background in mathematics.

Comment: About what Derek mentions: we studied first homomorphisms, isomorphism (relying heavily on what we *already* knew from linear alg.), and *after this* we got into normal subgroups, quotients and stuff. No big deal, slightly different approaches.

Comment: BTW, my approach is the same as in Rose's "A Course in Group Theory", Rotman's book, or in Herstein's "Abstract Algebra", but what Derek mentions is done in Robinson's book: a matter of taste, and as Derek's says: these subjects come pretty close together to each other, anyway.