# Let be $A=$ $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 8 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $H=SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ show that $HA=AH$

Tags: group-theory

Let be $A=$ $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
8 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}$

and $H=SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ show that $HA=AH$

Well i take $x\in H$ then $det(x)\neq 0$

and $xA=Ax'$ because $A\in GL_n(R)$ and $Sl_n(R)$ is normal in $GL_n(R)$ is right?

Comment: It looks as if the idea is to *prove* that $SL_2(\Bbb R)$ is normal in $GL_2(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Wich we have already proved, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359976/is-sl-n-mathbbr-a-normal-subgroup-in-gl-n-mathbbr?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

This follows from   multiplicativity of the determinant. $HA$ is exactly the set $D$ of all 2 by 2 matrices with determinant $-2$. Indeed,
clearly $HA \subset D$ and if $M \in D$ then $H^{-1}D \in SL_2$. The same argument applies to $AH$.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the argument to show also that $SL_n$ is a normal subgroup of $GL_n$.